# using .find() method but get undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here I'm defining a function using .find() method, and it should return { name: 'Adidas', price: 95 }.Anyone knows why it returns 'undefined' instead?

```
    var shoes = [
  { name: 'Nike', price: 200 },
  { name: 'Red Wings', price: 250 },
  { name: 'Vans', price: 150 },
  { name: 'Converse', price: 160 },
  { name: 'Reebok', price: 130 },
  { name: 'New Balance', price: 175 },
  { name: 'Adidas', price: 95 },
  { name: 'Keds', price: 140 },
  { name: 'Crocs', price: 135 }
];



const findWhere = function (array, criteria) {

  const key = Object.keys(criteria)[0];
  criteria = criteria[key];

  const result = array.find(ele => ele.key === criteria);
  return result;
};

const myShoe = findWhere(shoes, {price: 95});
console.log(myShoe);
```

Comment: You're checking `ele.key`, not `ele[key]`. Since that field doesn't exist, it will never find a match.

Comment: `ele.key` doesn't exist on `shoes` array

Answer (score 5):

You've used `ele.key` which accesses the literal `key` property on `ele`.

And since there is no `key` property on any of these objects:

```
{ name: 'Crocs', price: 135 }
```

`ele.key` is always `undefined`, meaning you get no matches.

Use brackets like you had earlier (`criteria = criteria[key];`):

```
const result = array.find(ele => ele[key] === criteria);
//                                  ^   ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ele.key` to `ele[key]`

```
const result = array.find(ele => ele[key] === criteria);
```